# Multiple optionLabelField in Fluid

Tags: php, html, forms, fluid, typo3-flow

I've got a select field in a fluid template and need two attributes for the optionLabelField. How can I handle this? That doesn't work:

```
<f:form.select property="person" id="person" options="{persons}" optionLabelField="prename name" />
```

Thanks, Pete

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own getter in your model `person`. Put the name of the getter without "get" prefix (e.g. fullname instead of getFullname) in `optionLabelField`.

Answer (score 0):

I would write my own ViewHelper that overwrites the SelectViewHelper from fluid. There you can make it possible that optionLabelField takes a comma seperated list and handles it how you need it.

[Developing a custom ViewHelper](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html)